# Unable to simulate real clicks and acquire desired result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting use jQuery to simulate the process of pasting this link

> steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M191782551910023971A6657788912D9818426115975581183

into the input field at https://beta.glws.org/ and clicking the "Check" button in order to acquire [this](http://image.prntscr.com/image/7b4da3996d9e499cbba5520bf85e0855.png) result.

The following is my code

```
$('input').select().val("steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M564455421073965484A6657119277D16476560725308262707");
$('.btn-check:contains("Check")').trigger("click");
```

but it doesn't work as it should and I get [THIS](http://image.prntscr.com/image/4f70f11c6c464fbfa0079fea9ff2fbf7.png) instead of the desired result :(
How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you should re-write this question. The answer depends on what you're trying to do, and 'simulate the process of pasting this link' ins't very clear.

Comment: Those result images  don't men anything to us with regard to your code. Show relevant html . See [mcve]